# ReactNative Webview - a way to control keyboard settings(auto-correct/capitalize) for a webview/whole app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I have a webview (using react-native-webview) which has a small text input form.

I would like to disable auto-capitalization and auto-correct on the keyboard which pops up when the input form fields come into focus.

I have looked at the library docs and don't see an option to configure that. I know there is an option to disable these fields with a TextInput component, but implementing the form directly in my app is not an option.

If there is a way to disable these keyboard settings across the whole app, that would also work.

Is there a way to configure the webview to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Thanks

Comment: did you remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found how it can be done for the entire app.

Android - disable keyboard settings for all TextInput:

1. Open file android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
2. Add new style, for customise all inputs in app:

   ```
   <style name="AppEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
       <item name="android:privateImeOptions">disableToolbar=true</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. Connect this style to your own style (which you use in AndroidManifest.xml):

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       ...
       <item name="editTextStyle">@style/AppEditTextStyle</item>
   </style>
   ```

Disable keyboard settings for all input inside WebView:

To override privateImeOptions I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package I did not find another way how to get access to privateImeOptions.

```
 diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewManager.java b/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewManager.java
 index c575db7..1b79f72 100644
 --- a/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewManager.java
 +++ b/node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewManager.java
 @@ -20,6 +20,8 @@ import android.text.TextUtils;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Gravity;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 +import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
 +import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
 @@ -1491,6 +1493,12 @@ public class RNCWebViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<WebView> {
      protected boolean nestedScrollEnabled = false;
      protected ProgressChangedFilter progressChangedFilter;
 
 +    @Override
 +    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
 +      outAttrs.privateImeOptions = "disableToolbar=true";
 +      return super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
 +    }
 +
      /**
      * WebView must be created with an context of the current activity
      * <p>
```